# Scale widget not displaying

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scale

This is my code and the scale bar does not display. Any suggestion?

```
from tkinter import *

self.mAsk = Scale(root, orient="horizontal", from_=1, to=16, label = "Mines", resolution = 1, sliderlength=25)
root=Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least three problems here:

- You try to use the global `root` before defining it, so your program is just going to raise a `NameError`.
- You're assigning something to `self.mAsk` when you don't have anything named `self`, so that's also going to raise a `NameError`. (Do you not understand what classes are, and why `self` appears in methods of classes in many tkinter examples?)
- You're not calling `pack`, `grid`, or `place` to actually place `mAsk` on the parent window. See the chapters on the three different Geometry Managers in the [Tkinter book](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm) if you have no idea what this means.

If you fix all three, then it works:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
mAsk = Scale(root, orient="horizontal", from_=1, to=16, label = "Mines", resolution = 1, sliderlength=25)
mAsk.pack()
root.mainloop()
```